# Hiding output from a vectorized function

Tags: r, functional-programming, vectorization

## Background

In this example, I would like to run `rm` only on objects that are found in the provided environment.

*Analogical results can be achieved via `suppressWarnings` but I want to make use of the Vectorize.*

## Example

```
# Create two objects to delete
a <- 1
c <- 2
# b doesn't exist

Vectorize(
    FUN = function(object) {
        invisible(rm(object))
    },
    vectorize.args = "object"
) -> vf_rem

# Run function only on existing objects
vf_rem(object = Filter(f = exists, x = c("a", "b", "c")))
```

The function correctly removes **`a`** and **`c`** and does not emit the warning when encountering name of missing object **`"b"`**.

### Problem

The `vf_rem` still outputs an object to console:

```
>> vf_rem(object = Filter(f = exists, x = c("a", "b", "c")))
$a
NULL

$c
NULL
```

I would like to hide it, which I've fruitlessly attempted with `invisible` call.

### Desired output

#### Not showing anything

```
>> vf_rem(object = Filter(f = exists, x = c("a", "b", "c")))
>> # Combing back to prompt, nothing is printed
>> # .Last.values contains lst_res from lines below
```

#### To object as any other function

```
>> vf_rem(object = Filter(f = exists, x = c("a", "b", "c"))) -> lst_res
>> lst_res
# Shows list
>>    $a
    NULL

    $c
    NULL
```

Comment: As an aside: Side-effects are problematic. Therefore, don’t hide side-effects of your statement at the end of the line, place them prominently at the beginning. Meaning: don’t *ever* use `->` assignment (except, if you insist, in the interactive shell), since assignment is a side-effect.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, I’m fan of `->` but I’ll remember your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular example, you can invoke `rm` with a vector:

```
vf_rem = function (objects) rm(list = objects)
```

In general, the following should do the trick:

```
vf_fun = function (objects) invisible(Vectorize(fun)(objects))
```